# parsing string as an xml using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a requirement, where input is a wel formed xml string. I need to traverse through that string and get some specific value.

input:

```
<Session>
   <Store>
      <Name>myname</name>
      <ContactId>1234</ContactId>
   </Store>
</Session>
```

I need to get the value of ContactId and store it in a variable...
Please help.

Comment: You mean splitting the input and store the value "1234" in a variable. Is that you are expecting?

Comment: I need to traverse through the request and get the ContactId value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:-

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/Session/Store/ContactId/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: No, this is not working. The input is string. I am not able to apply xPath.

Comment: To give more Info, Session is the only node there, remaining is a string, I need to convert that string to XML and read the ContactVendor node. Its like converting string to XML node-set.

Comment: Ok then from where **Store** node is coming.

Comment: here is my input.     <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<S:Header/>
<S:Body>
<OrderInfo xmlns="">
<SessionInfo xsi:type="xsd:string">
&lt;StoreInfo>&lt;Vendor>IBM322&lt;/Vendor>&lt;StoreNo>5555&lt;/StoreNo>&lt;Country>US&lt;/Country>&lt;/StoreInfo></SessionInfo>
</OrderInfo>
<DrInfo xsi:type="xsd:string">
</DrInfo>
</S:Body>
<S:Envelope>    I need the value of vendor..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="Session">
    <Store>
            <Name>myname</name>
            <ContactId>1234</ContactId>
    </Store>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($Session)/Store/ContactId/text()">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```